# How to apply a patch via plugin?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, patch

I need to apply [this patch](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/52589/52589.patch). A traditional way is to SSH to my hosting and use the Unix command `patch < path_to_patch`. However, this will be lost after a new update. So it seems that the long-term way is to do this via plugin. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Presumably if there is an update, it will include this patch, no?

Comment: maybe. But I want to apply it now

Comment: You miss my point. If the update includes the patch then you don't have to worry about an update erasing the change, do you?

Comment: yes. It can even that the new update has a better patch. This can lead to a situation that I screw up the update. However, there is still another point that I just want to learn more about WordPress

Comment: Well this is a CSS update, so the right way to do it is not going to be applying an SVN patch with a plugin. The right way to do it would be to just take the CSS changes and putting them in Additional CSS.

Comment: But applying this patch isn't going to ruin anything. It's just going to be replaced entirely. So if the update has a better patch, that's a win-win because it's going to replace your change with the better one.

Comment: but why is putting the changes in the Additional CSS the right way? With a plugin I can manage all changes I made in one place, not just this patch. Plus that in this patch there are a lot of CSS changes, and I see there are changes in files that I don't know how to put in the stylesheet. For example in the file `ie-editor.css.map`

Comment: That’s a style map. It’s a development tool. The only relevant changes are to the CSS file.